# Is the direction of the longest line of a polytope unique?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, convex-polytopes, convex-geometry

The question pertains to a polytope that is generated by the intersection of an affine subspace with a hypercube in $p$ dimensions.

The affine subspace is given by:

$X  \mbox{ u} = y$

where

$u$ ∈ $\mathbb{R}^p$.

$X$ is a $m$ × $p$ matrix with $m$ < $p$ and

$y$ is a $m$ dimensional vector.

The hypercube is given by:

$0$ ≤ $u$ ≤ $u_{max}$

The longest line of this polytope is clearly one of the lines that join the vertices of the polytope. My question is:

Is the direction of the longest line independent of $u_{max} \mbox{&nbsp}$ for some $u_{max}$ ≥ u* ?

Some simulations I did in Matlab indicates that the answer to the above question is yes but I am not sure if this will hold in general. I am assuming of course that the polytope actually resides in the hypercube defined by $0$ ≤ $u$ ≤ $u_{max}$.

Any pointers to relevant literature in applied math or some approaches to answer the question would be very helpful.

Thanks

Comment: Any chance you want to edit the LaTeX symbols?

Comment: Sorry for the dumb question but I work only on vector spaces over the reals: This appears to be a question on a finite discrete space of some sort?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I do not usually use LaTeX. I cleaned up the LaTeX glitches.

Comment: @Deane:

Cleaned up notation to indicate that the question relates to real spaces.

Comment: What ordering are you using on vectors?  Pointwise?

Comment: @Qiaochu: I am afraid I do not understand your question. My knowledge of math is fairly limited.

Comment: Pointwise ordering is the only that makes sense here. I.e., $u\le v$ means `$u_i\le v_i$` for each $i$. The terminology is off here, though: Hyperplanes are unbounded (and of dimension one less than the containing space). We are looking at a polytope which is the intersection of an affine subspace with the standard hypercube in $\mathbb{R}^p$.

Comment: (Argh! I forgot that one can't get LaTeX formatting in comments beyond the fifth.)

Comment: To expand on Harald's comment a bit, assuming that the rank of X is m, what Srikant is asking is: "What's the longest segment contained inside the polytope formed by intersecting an m-plane (specified by X and y) with the hypercube of side-length u_{max} in R^p?  Is the direction of this segment fixed if u_{max} is large enough?"

Comment: It's not clear to me if u_{max} is a scalar or a vector. The statement could be understood either way. I hope Srikant can clarify. (Also, it would be nice to be sure that X isn't assumed to have positive entries, as often happens in linear programming.) 

Comment: The way I have defined u_{max} above - it is a vector. However, all elements of u_{max} have the same value and hence we have a hypercube in p dimensions. X can have positive or negative values. The original context in which the above issue arises would constrain X to have only +1, 0 or -1 values but I did not mention this constraint as I felt that the general problem would have a positive answer.

Comment: I edited the question to fix  the terminology.

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer to your question is yes.  **edit: NO**

First I'll set some notation.  Assume that $X$ is rank $m$.  I'll denote by $L$ the m-dimensional plane defined by $X u = y$.  Subscripts will denote components of vectors.  Instead of $u_{max}$ I'll use $v$.  I'll denote by $A_{v}$ the hypercube $0\leq u_i\leq v$ for $1\leq i\leq p$.  The problem as stated is about the intersection between $A_v$ and $L$, which is a polytope I'll call $P_v$.

We can rescale the coordinates by taking $u\rightarrow vu'$ so that $A_v$ has side length 1 in the $u'$ coordinates.  Under this transformation, $L$ keeps its orientation but is shifted.  In particular, $L$ is now defined by $X (vu')=y$, or $X u'=y'$ where $y' = 1/v*y$.  As $v$ gets larger and larger, $y'$ gets closer and closer to the origin.  Note that if $y$ were the zero vector, your problem is scale invariant and hence has a positive answer.

If $y$ was not the zero vector, then to understand what $P_v$ looks like for large $v$, we need to understand how a slice through the hypercube behaves very close to one of its vertices.  Is there a result (for convex polytopes in general?) that tells us that the "shape" of a slice is stable to small translations of the slicing plane when we're close to a vertex?  I haven't found any counter-examples in the low-dimensional cases I've (unsystematically) tried.

**edit:** I spoke way to soon.  Consider a plane slicing through the 3-dimensional cube such that the plane makes right angles with the top and bottom faces of the cube.  In general the intersection will be a rectangle whose aspect ratio changes and becomes skinnier and skinnier as the plane gets closer to a vertex.  The direction of the longest segment in this rectangle (either of the diagonals) obviously **does not** stabilize.  But is there a positive result lurking here for suitably "generic" planes?

Comment: A clarification: Do you mean the transformation $u'\rightarrow u/v$ instead of $u \rightarrow vu$? 

Comment: Yes, sorry.  I've updated my answer.

Comment: How about this: Define $S$ as the set of points where $L$ intersects the half-planes defined by $u'_i = 0$ and u'_j >= 0 for all $j$ not equal to $i$. I guess we are done if we can show that for some $v > v^*$ all the points in the set $S$ are less than $1$. 

The above would suggest that $P_v$ lies entirely in the hypercube and hence 'retains' its shape. Does that make sense?

ps; I am unable to edit my comments after posting. I hope the above is clear.


Comment: I've updated my answer to show that the answer to your question is no.  For planes L which approach only one vertex, I still think the answer is yes.  @Srikant, I'm not sure what you mean exactly.  P_v is defined to be the intersection of the hypercube A_v (unit hypercube in the rescaled coordinates) with L, so it always lies in a hypercube... Considering the boundaries of P_v as you suggested might be a good approach though.

Comment: Never mind my comment reg $P_v$. The argument does not work. However, I am confused about why you think a rectangle that is perpendicular to the top and the bottom faces of a cube becomes skinnier as $v$ increases. Such a plane will always have the same shape irrespective of the value of $v$. As $v$ increases, the plane shifts towards the origin but retains its orientation. (Note: The longest line is not unique as either diagonal is a longest line but that is a different issue.)



Comment: You are right that the plane retains its orientation, however the shape of the rectangle that is the intersection with the cube changes.  For my example, p=3, m=1, hence X u = y can be written as N.u=a where N is a normal vector to the plane L and a is the distance of L to the origin along N.  Let N = (1,1,0) and a=1.  Then the intersection of L with A_v (for v>1) is the rectangle with vertices (1,0,0), (0,1,0), (0,1,v), (1,0,v).  One longest segment is the one joining (1,0,0) and (0,1,v) which is parallel to (1,-1,-v) which clearly changes as v increases.